# Java method using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I am learning Java and discovering that a little bit of knowledge is confusing.
The goal is to write a  method that is the equivalent of the n! function. I am using a for loop to multiply a variable declared outside the method. All I get back is 0.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//
// Complete the method to return the product of
// all the numbers 1 to the parameter n (inclusive)
// @ param n
// @ return n!

public class MathUtil
{
   public int total;

   public int product(int n)
  {
   for (int i = 1; i == n; i ++)
   {
       total = total * i;

    }
    return total;

  }
}
```

Comment: Read this line of code adn tell me what seems wrong with it: `for (int i = 1; i == n; i ++)` Hint: initialization, condition, incrementation.

Comment: Total is not initialized with a value.

Comment: @kirbyquerby Irrelevant

Comment: @Kon. No it's not, lmao.

Comment: Please learn some basic debugging skills.  Learn to use a debugger, or at least print out information at some meaningful positions.  You should be able to solve the problems easily yourself

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's always the simple things that appear invisible.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a lot of problems in your code:

- It does not make sense to make it an instance method.
- You have not initialize your `total` to a reasonable value.
- The condition in your for loop is wrong
- Method is not given a meaningful name
- Messy indentation
- (The list keeps growing...)

So here is a slightly improved version

```
public class MathUtil
{
  //
  // Complete the method to return the product of
  // all the numbers 1 to the parameter n (inclusive)
  // @ param n
  // @ return n!

  public static int factorial(int n)
  {
    int total = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i ++)
    {
      total = total * i;
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

so that you can call it as `MathUtil.product(123)` instead of some weird `new MathUtil().product(123)`

Personally I would rather do something like

```
result = n;
while (--n > 0) {
    result *= n;
}
return result;
```

Comment: Also, product is is a bad name in the first place. It doesn't appropriately describe the functionality. `factorial` would be a better name, since that's what is actually does.

Comment: @Bryan Yes! I was planning to mention that too! Dunno why I missed that at last. Thanks for reminding

Comment: That last bit is clever! I may use that! I never considered using the commutative property to do the multiplication in reverse. I've always done factorials by counting up. It might be helpful to make a small note on the difference between pre vs post increment though, since your compact solution hinges on it whereas the for loop does not.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the initialization. Now I added the default value to 1. And you also have to change the condition. The for loop has to go on as long as the var i is smaller or equal to n.

```
public class MathUtil
{
  public int total = 1;

  public int product(int n)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i ++)
    {
     total = total * i;
    }
   return total;

  }
 }
```

Comment: I did correct it. Now it should be fine, because you go from one to N.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't initialized total, therefore it's 0. Whenever you multiply 0 with anything, you will get 0 as result.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int total = 1;

    public int product(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            total = total * i;

        }
        return total;

    }
```

you havent initialized total. It defaults to 0. Then when you multiple anything with total, you get 0 as result

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than just solving it and posting code